# Google Maps Android API - Unable to create project to get key

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to get a project going for Android using the Google Maps Android API.

Following this guide:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/

I seem to be getting stuck when I try to create a project in the google developer console. It keeps failing after a short time and I get notifications saying that it failed to create the project.

Searching for a solution to this I found that people needed to enable something by going to admin.google.com. Problem is when I go there it says "admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com".

Do I need to upgrade my regular gmail account to a G Suite account to be able to use the Google Maps API? I wouldn't think so seeing as I am unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: Try going to https://console.cloud.google.com/ and create a project from there. If you get a 'couldn't create project' just wait for a while before trying again.

Comment: Jared, are you using a domain account or a free GMail account.  I find that I can create one using my personal GMail account, but not my Work (Google Server) account.  If this is the issue, and you've managed to solve it, can you please post where you enable it in the Admin panel, as I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what was causing this. But I tried again later and it works. So I guess we'll just call it a temporary google issue.